# Send HTTPS request in React Native through WebView

Tags: javascript, react-native, ssl, webview

I'm beginner in React Native and mobile development in general, so, sorry if my question is stupid.

Reading about SSL certificate pinning in native apps and the problems with keeping it up to date I wonder if it's possible to send HTTPS request through WebView, so in this case the certificate validation is going to be done by the browser.

The idea is to implement sort of communication layer with webview and fetch data inside it.

Any ideas regarding this?

Comment: Tried to create a POC and it seems to be working.
https://snack.expo.io/@muzikant/fetch-test